# OpenStack Swift - alias, symlink for a stored object

Tags: alias, symlink, openstack, openstack-swift

I have the application (App A) which pushes each 2 seconds an image to some SWIFT container. The image name is a timestamp.

Another app (app B) should get the last container image and show it in  tag.

The problem is that app B does not know what was the last timestamp.

My first approach was to simulate a symlink or alias - I push always last.png file (and before it I issue a copy command to rename already existing in swift last.png).

I have to make 2 additional operations (copy and delete).

Is there any more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use the versioning feature of the swift API?

Swift handles two containers, one storing old versions, automatically named with the timestamp suffix, and the other storing the most recent version of the file.

Lest say the containers are: backup and backup_versions.Also you have to link them in order to tell swift which is the container storing file versions.

So, every time you upload a file, swift will take care of the process automatically. When it comes to downloading, you just need to download the file from the backup container, which will be the mos recent version of the file, and there is no need to know the timestamp, as you only need the name.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Intresting tweek. Actually we moved our solution form using OpenStack. But I note your comment! Thanks